Sprint Boot Jpa Bidirectional Cycle Issue
    @ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "TeachersId")
private TeachersEntity teachersId;


@OneToMany(mappedBy = "teachersId",cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JsonManagedReference
private List<PaperEntity> paperId;

the Teachers id should be shown in PaperDetails Table Only
I have created a crud operation in sts but during the time of fetching i am getting infinte cycle issue .I have created Bidirectional mapping using OneToMany , My requirment is it should be bidirectional only because i dont want create new table for the Storage[Its The image which has infinye cycle issue ](https://i.sstatic.net/OlUMDM51.png)...
I have Used JsonManagerReferce and JsonBackRefernce More over Its lazy loading also .
//Please help me with that
I used Bidirectional Mapping.SO for that i have set it as Lazy Loading . I have also Used @JsonManagerRefernce ANd @jsonBackRefernce
The infinte Cycle issue should Stop .

For your usecase, you can use @JsonIgnore on the field you don't want in your JSON response, i.e., it will not be serialized.
@JsonIgnore
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "teachersId",cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JsonManagedReference
private List<PaperEntity> paperId;

Alternatively, if you wanna go with @JsonManagedReference and @JsonBackReference, you will need to use both together- @JsonBackReference on the field that you want to omit from the json response, and @JsonManagedReference on the field that you want to keep in the response.
@JsonManagedReference
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "TeachersId")
private TeachersEntity teachersId;

@JsonBackReference
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "teachersId",cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JsonManagedReference
private List<PaperEntity> paperId;

Take a look at this answer to know when to use which way
Side Note:
The property names in your example seems to be unusual, usually you do not name your associated entities as teacherId, paperId etc. they do not represent the primary key of your associated entities, but the entity themselves, so for example, for teacherId it should be teacher only, and for paperId it should be papers, as it is a list of PaperEntity. So your mappedBy will become mappedBy = "teacher" reflecting the same name.
